# Display static HTML file for Vue.js root URL

Tags: javascript, vue.js, cloudflare

I'm new to Vue and am trying to figure out the best way to do the below.

Let's use example.com as our domain name.

We have a Vue.js app deployed that allows our customers to create their own subdirectory in our Vue.js app (e.g., example.com/user1page and example.com/user2page). Right now example.com goes to a Vue.js login page

Marketing recently sent us a home page (built in pure HTML/CSS/JS) that they need  to display at example.com. Is it possible for me to upload the HTML/CSS/JS for that page in a Vue static asset folder and render that for example.com; then render our actual Vue.js app for anything example.com/*?

Due to business reasons we cannot:

1. Change the vue.js app to a different domain or subdomain (because customers have already published pages)
2. Change the marketing homepage to a different domain / subdomain / subdirectory

As an aside, we're using Clouflare for our DNS. Unfortunately their page rules won't be able to solve this issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks very much!
Ed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would solve this with a webserver configuration if you have access to it.
In NGINX you can define different locations with different root-folders.

So if a user access to main page it would it the first route and serve the static page and if it would it the regex for the client page it would serve the vue application (you could also specify the vue server here)

```
location / {
     root /var/www/static-html-folder;
}
    
location /paths-to-clientpages {
      root /var/www/vuepage;
}
```

For the location paths you can use regex to match all routes

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately we don't have access to webserver configuration (we are using Netlify as our host and Cloudflare as our DNS--we don't have our own server). I will try and see if I can do something with Cloudflare workers or Netlify rewrites to replicate what you've posted above.

Comment: I think with cloudflare page rules you can use asterics to match specific routes, as described on this post
[Cloudflare] (https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200172286-Configuring-URL-forwarding-or-redirects-with-Cloudflare-Page-Rules)

Comment: We were able to accomplish this in Netlify using a 200 redirect (from Netlify: "redirects with this status code will change the server response without changing the URL in the browser address bar"). Your answer would've worked for most other folks, so I marked it as accepted. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that the way to do this in Netlify is to add the following command to your toml file:

```
[[redirects]]
from = "/"
to = "your marketing page URL"
status = 200
force = true
```